# Input range style changed mysteriously

Tags: html, css, firefox, input, range

I've tried styling my `input type range` of my webpage. Unfortunately i'm seeing a rounded slider button instead of a default bullet. Of course it is looking good, but cannot figure out where it is coming from.

I'm seeing this in `mozilla firefox`.

This is the [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/mYzfP/)

**EDIT:** just found that it is because of change in `background-color`. But why there is a change in slider bullet style if `background-color` changed.

Answer (score 0):

The default rendering of the slider is done with OS native theming: the browser asks the OS to just draw a slider control at a particular location on the screen.

But if you change the background, that implementation strategy no longer works, since you can't as the OS to draw a slider control with a different background than default slider controls (at least not across all operating systems).  So at that point the browser will fall back on painting the control itself.  It will try to make it look like the OS-default rendering to some extent, but it can't do this reliably, since the OS-default rendering can be pretty arbitrary depending on what OS theme you have enabled...